# Extract private key from Domino keyring

Tags: ibm, ibm-domino, private-key, certificate

I'm trying to use a multipurpose certificate on an infrastucture that contains a Domino 7 server.
To accomplish this, I tried:

1. Generate a CSR outside of Domino: I'm able to use the produced certificate everywhere but not on Domino because it requires to generate a keyring and the correspondent CSR
2. Generate the keyring and the CSR in Domino: everithing (services) work well in Domino, but I'm not able to extract the private key to use the certificate for other purposes

For the attempt 2. I found that someone used a tool named IKEYMAN from IBM; it's been quite difficult to find a download for IKEYMAN.
IKEYMAN can open a Domino keyring and export it to KDB format or in a .class; I was not able to use any of the formats IKEYMAN exports to extract the private key. [Someone on Lotus forums](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd8forum.nsf/Customer/6208adc5e5e12b0885257721004f83e7?OpenDocument) says that he did the trick, but I'm missing something: in the keyring I was not able to find any private keys.

My question is: can I extract the private key from a Domino keyring? In the case of the need to use a tool, where exactly can I find this tool?

Comment: I haven't foun an answer... I ended up with the 'certificate copy' function provided by the CA supplier: different copies of the same certificate produced from different CSRs. I agree for the move to SF.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the link to IBM's public Download site.. Hope it helps

ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/lotus/tools/Domino/gsk5-ikeyman.zip

If the above link doesn't work, try this:
https://ftpmirror.your.org/pub/misc/ftp.software.ibm.com/software/lotus/tools/Domino/gsk5-ikeyman.zip

Comment: For me IKEYMAN does not start. When I run _runikeyman.bat_ from command prompt it just shows the path etc and returns to "C:\Program Files\IBM\GSK5>". Nothing is launched. I've tried many instructions including this one http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/5/d8153f5591411ed185257d2f00765653 but the result is always the same. I've tried it on 3 PCs and one server (Win 10, 7 and 2003). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

IBM support helped me on this one.

1. Download the [new key ring tool](http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?parent=ibm~Lotus&product=ibm/Lotus/Lotus%20Domino&release=9.0.1.2&platform=All&function=fixId&fixids=KYRTool_9x_ClientServer&includeSupersedes=0) and save the appropriate version to program directory of your Notes client.
2. `kyrtool show keys -k <path to keyring file>`